# %increase of elemental effect chance

Tags: borderlands-2

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is “+% chance” additive or multiplicative?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/85158/is-chance-additive-or-multiplicative)

- How do "%elemental effect chance increases" (e.g. the talent "[Flicker](http://borderlands.wikia.com/wiki/Flicker)"
  form Maya/Siren) apply their effect?

I can think of 2 ways:

Lets say weapon %elemental effect chance = 10%

Increase = 50%

Method 1: effective %elemental effect chance -> 15% (increase 50% of base chance)

Method 2: effective %elemental effect chance -> 60% (increase by the 50%)

- Furthermore how do these effects stack when multiple are present?